# IF condition inside for loop in c#.net

Tags: oracle, c#-3.0

In below code, `if(_drone["CODE"]  =="zen")` inside the for loop is not working,eventhough `_drone["code"]` contain zen.

Only those records with value `zen .nedd` to be added `to_dr (_abc.rows.ans(_dr)`

```
           public DataTable InitInGroup(DataTable _dtdoctor, string _Folio, string _IsCom = "No", string _CODE = "")

         {

             DataTable _abc = GetDoc("~", "~", "~", "~");



    if (_dtdoctor != null)

        {

                foreach (DataRow _drone in _dtdoctor.Rows)

                {

                   if (_drone["CODE"] == "zen"
```

Edit

Not working with the one you mentioned .As above another scenario stated below.I want to compare the session value with the database value

```
    foreach (DataRow dr28 in _DTU_ABC.Rows)

                {

                   string ss = HttpContext.Current.Session["ADMIN"].ToString();



                    IF (dr28[_CODE].ToString == ss)

                    {

                    cmd28.Parameters.Clear();

                    OracleHelper.CreateParameter(ref cmd28, ref param28, "@NUMBER", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, dr28["Number"].ToString());

                    OracleHelper.CreateParameter(ref cmd28, ref param28, "@SITECODE", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, dr28["CODE"].ToString());

                    cmd28.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }

                }
```

Comment: What happens when you step through the code using a debugger?

Comment: After if statement,it is going back to the foreach statement.(Not going inside the if)

Answer (score 0):

_drone["CODE"] returns an **object**. Try this instead:

```
if (_drone["CODE"].ToString() == "zen")
```

Comment: Pls see Edit portion